# Update User Profile Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hello I have just started in Laravel and am trying to update the users profile:
My route:

```
Route::patch('users/{user}/update',  ['as' => 'users.update', 'uses' => 'UserController@update']);
```

My View:

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('users.update', $user)}}">

    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('patch') }}

    <input type="text" name="name"  value="{{ $user->name }}" />
    <input type="email" name="email"  value="{{ $user->email }}" />


    <input type="password" name="password" />

    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" />

    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

and my update function in UserController:

```
public function update(User $user)
    { 

        $this->validate(request(), [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        ]);

        $user->name = Request::input('name');
        $user->email = Request::input('email');

        $user->save();
        Flash::message('Your account has been updated!');
        return back();
    }
```

I dont get any errors yet my user profiles aren't updated.Can sb help me?

Comment: First try adding some dd() to action to see what is going on - dump request data and user to see if you get correct data.

Comment: @Bostjan I just did the dd($user) in controller and it returns `code #original: array:10  `among others

Comment: What about dd(Request::all()) to see if submited values are ok?

Comment: @Bostjan I think the error is in the `        $this->validate(request(), [
`

Comment: @Bostjan Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::all() should not be called statically...if I call it after $this...it gives no error and no output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think fields aren't updated because validations fails. If you check your form you have four (4) fields with name 'email'. With this it fails validator for email.

You can try displaying errors in blade file: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

And I suggest to inject request as method parameters. Like this;

```
public function update(User $user, Request $request)
{ 
    $data = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
    ]);

    $user->fill($data);
    $user->save();
    Flash::message('Your account has been updated!');
    return back();
}
```

Comment: The email must be a valid email address.P.S the email is a valid email address

Comment: Did you fix your form? You have 4 email fields

Comment: thanks it seems that the error has been the email fields